# How to show that the space of polynomials is not complete

Tags: metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Denote by $P[0,1]$ the set of all polynomials $p\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$; this is a vector space. Endow $P[0,1]$ with the norm $$\| p\|=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}{| p(t)|}.$$
I want to show that this particular norm on $P[0,1]$ isn't complete.

I think that, for example, the sequence $$p_n(x)=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\dfrac{x^n}{n!}\qquad (n\in \mathbb{N})$$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ to the function $e^{x}$ that isn't a polynomial. Then $(p_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, but it doesn't converge in $P[0,1]$. Now, how I can prove this, but more formally?

Greetings...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\left\Vert p_{n}-p_{m}\right\Vert =\sup_{\left[  0,1\right]  }\left\vert
%TCIMACRO{\dsum \limits_{i=0}^{n}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}}
%EndExpansion
\frac{x^{i}}{i!}-%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum \limits_{i=0}^{m}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m}}
%EndExpansion
\frac{x^{i}}{i!}\right\vert =\sup_{\left[  0,1\right]  }\left\vert
%TCIMACRO{\dsum \limits_{i=m+1}^{n}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{n}}
%EndExpansion
\frac{x^{i}}{i!}\right\vert \leq%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum \limits_{i=m+1}^{n}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{n}}
%EndExpansion
\frac{1}{i!}.$ Noting that $%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum \limits_{i=0}^{n}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}}
%EndExpansion
\frac{1}{i!}\rightarrow e$, so $\left(  p_{n}\right)  $ is a Cauchy sequence.
Now, assume that $p_{n}\rightarrow p\in P\left[  0,1\right]  $. Hence
$p_{n}\left(  x\right)  \rightarrow p\left(  x\right)  $ $\forall x\in\left[
0,1\right]  .$ So  $p\left(  x\right)  =e^{x}\in P\left[  0,1\right]  .$
Assume $e^{x}=p\left(  x\right)  =%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum \limits_{i=0}^{M}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^{M}}
%EndExpansion
a_{i}x^{i}$. Then $e^{x}=p^{\left(  M+1\right)  }\left(  x\right)  =0$ which
is impossible.

Comment: Oh thanks!!, very clear answer :D

Comment: @user72012 I've a question about your Cauchy sequence. How you are saying that $(p_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence ? In order to show that we have to show that $\left\Vert p_n-p_m\right \Vert \to 0$ as $n,m \to \infty$. It is not clear from your proof..!

Comment: @Empty every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence. And, pn is converging in [0,1] by a lot of criterion that you learn in mathematical analysis.

Comment: Very beautiful and organized. But seeing this demonstration I had two doubts.
1) Why do you conclude that $(p_n)$ is a sequence of Cauchy? I understood that it is smaller than $e$ and not that a any positive $\epsilon$.
2) I did not use the conclusion $e^x = p^{M+1}(x)=0$.

Comment: Why it's is true? $p_{n}\rightarrow p\in P\left[  0,1\right]$ hence $p_{n}(x) \rightarrow p(x)$ This is intution about compactness $[0,1]$?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe $\{p_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence since $||p_n-p_m|| = \sum_{i =m+1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}$. Because the entire sequence ($i=0$ to $\infty$) converges to $e$, we can choose $N$ sufficiently large such that $m,n>N$ implies that what we're left with is a portion of the tail of a convergent sequence which we can make arbitrarily small. Hence, $||p_n-p_m|| < \epsilon $ and so $\{p_n\}$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

From the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem we have that polynomials are dense in $C([0, 1])$ with your same norm and if $P([0,1])$ was complete then $C([0, 1])=P([0,1])$.